# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.databasesqlite/com.databasesqlite.MainActivity}

Tags: android, sqlite

okay guys. i really got stuck with this program -_-! when i running the program, shows up so much error. heres: the whole logcat:

```
1. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sqlitetolistview/com.sqlitetolistview.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: db (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT nama, alamat, _id FROM db
2.  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
3.  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
4.  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
5.  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
6.  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
7.  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
8.  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
9.  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10.     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11.     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12.     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
13.     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
14. Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: db (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT nama, alamat, _id FROM db
15.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
16.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
17.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
18.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
19.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
20.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
21.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
22.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
23.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
24.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
24.     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
26.     at com.sqlitetolistview.MainActivity.muat_ulang(MainActivity.java:33)
27.     at com.sqlitetolistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
28.     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
29.     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
30.     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

i have a MainActivity.java like this:

```
package com.sqlitetolistview;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.BaseColumns;
 import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private CursorAdapter data_sumber;
    private static final String kolom[] = {"nama", "alamat",BaseColumns._ID };
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView view = getListView();
        view.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null));
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        this.muat_ulang();
        this.tambahdata();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void muat_ulang()
    {
        Cursor data = db.query("db", kolom, null, null, null, null,null);
        data_sumber = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, data, kolom,new int[] { R.id.nama, R.id.alamat });
        setListAdapter(data_sumber);
    }

    public void tambahdata()
    {
        helper.tambah(db);
        this.muat_ulang();
}
}
```

and the xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layoutBaris"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/nama"
        android:text="Nama"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dip" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alamat"
        android:text="Alamat"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here the DBHelper.java:

```
 package com.sqlitetolistview;

   import java.util.Random;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

   public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //db.execSQL("");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void tambah(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String[] nama_sis = new String[] { "Gede", "Okky", "Untung", "Puji", "Willy", "Ayus" };
        String[] alamat_sis = new String[] { "Denpasar", "Banyuwangi", "Situbondo", "Rogojampi", "Purwoharjo", "Rogojampi" };
        int lanjut = new Random().nextInt(6);
        String nama_in = nama_sis[lanjut];
        String alamat_in = alamat_sis[lanjut];
        //db.execSQL("");
    }
}
```

please help me to fix the error :) thanks

Comment: You should post the whole logcat

Comment: Can you post the DBHelper class also? Please make sure you have created a table called "db" in the overridden method
    `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class

Comment: @Egor i alredy post the whole logcat

Comment: @kimyr: If you look at the method onCreate in your DBHelper class, there is no statement that creates a table called db. Looks like that is the major cause.
Insert the table create statement as follows in onCreate method,
  `db.execSQL("create table table1 (" +
            "_id integer primary key auto increment)");`
Pardon me for syntax error, if any...

Please refer to this link for more details: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: @HarshSingal You should probably put this as an answer instead of a comment, so that kimyr can accept it. Otherwise, it will linger here as unanswered question.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, putting the comment as an answer,
@kimyr
If you look at the method onCreate in your `DBHelper` class, there is no statement that creates a table called db. Looks like that is the major cause. Insert the table create statement as follows in `onCreate method`,

```
db.execSQL("create table table1 (" + "_id integer primary key auto increment)");
```

Pardon me for syntax error, if any. Please refer to [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write create table query in OnCreate()

I think You have to refer [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) for Sqlite